# Viewpager background color bleeds through first page

Tags: android, background, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a viewpager inside a fragment that is exhibiting the following behaviour. Pages 2 onwards display correctly, but the first page is displayed as if it were behind the background of the container view - as if it had a lower z-index than the background (where z-indices increase towards the user) - refer to the images linked below.

The code for page instantiation is:

```
pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object item) {
        container.removeView((View) item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_selector, null, false);

        final ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);

        image.setImageResource(mImages.get(position));

        container.addView(layout);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object item) {
        return item.equals(view)
    }

});
```

..nothing particularly special.

Layout for the viewpager fragment is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#ff2288dd">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/help1" />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/text1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_margin="12dip" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/help2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and for the per-page image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Again, nothing out of the ordinary.

Behaviour is present on Froyo (2.2) and Gingerbread (2.3) on physical devices and emulators, as well as a physical device running 4.2.

The odder part is that when an image is touched to select it, a new fragment replaces the original viewpager fragment, and if the selected image is from the first page of the viewpager, the described behaviour is present there too - despite the fragments having entirely different layouts (and the new fragment having no defined background).

Layout for the selected-image fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Reference images below.

[First Page](http://tinypic.com/r/1zv8i3d/5)

[Transition to Second Page](http://tinypic.com/r/2m47oso/5)

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I think it is similar to something I am seeing.

Comment: Nope. I've since moved on to other projects, but if you're using a recent version of Android it's a little discouraging to see the issue may still be present.

Comment: Well it is only happening to me on 4.2 and below. I'm not 100% sure if this is the issue but sounds just like it. I've moved on as well.